# COBOL error with numeric variable, not numeric

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

### problem

I'm a beginner in COBOL and I'm running into this annoying problem which I can not find a solution for.
I want to add the value of the amount of sales to another numeric variable so that I can use it as a condition for a perform loop but when it tries to add that value to this new variable it triggers this error:

> "libcob: PROG-PAGOS-F.cbl: 57: 'WS-CANTIDAD-VENTAS' not numeric: '2  '
> WARNING - Implicit CLOSE of REG-VENDEDORES ('REG-MAESTRO.DAT')"

and I can not find a way around it; I'm stuck.

### current code (not finished)

What this program is supposed to do is output data of employees' salary, sells, price of each sell into a file and then do some other operations with them but I can't do any progress because of this error, I'd love some help, and perhaps some advices to makes this code better. Thank you!
My variables are in Spanish because I'm Argentinian, sorry if it's hard to understand.

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID.                PROG-PAGOS-F.
       AUTHOR.                    LUCAS GALEANO.
       DATE-WRITTEN.              1/2/2023.

       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.
           SELECT REG-VENDEDORES ASSIGN TO "REG-MAESTRO.DAT"
               ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

           SELECT REG-VENTAS     ASSIGN TO "REG-VENTAS-MAESTRO.DAT"
               ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

       DATA DIVISION.
       FILE SECTION.
       FD REG-VENDEDORES.
       01 VENDEDORES              PIC 9(11).

       FD REG-VENTAS.
       01 COBRO-VENTAS              PIC 9(5).


       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01 WS-VENDEDORES.
           05 WS-EMPLEADO            PIC 999.
           05 WS-SUELDO-BASE         PIC 9(5).
           05 WS-CANTIDAD-VENTAS     PIC 999.

       77 WS-COBROS                  PIC 9(5).
       77 WS-SUM-VENTAS              PIC 99.
       77 WS-CONTADOR                PIC 99 VALUE ZEROS.

       01 WS-TABLAS.
           05 WS-REGISTRO-COBROS     PIC 9(5)
                                     OCCURS 100 TIMES.

       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       BEGIN-OUTPUT.
           OPEN OUTPUT REG-VENDEDORES.
           DISPLAY "INGRESE DATOS SOLICITADOS".
           PERFORM INGRESO-DATOS-EMPLEADOS.
           PERFORM UNTIL WS-VENDEDORES EQUALS SPACES
               WRITE VENDEDORES FROM WS-VENDEDORES
               PERFORM INGRESO-DATOS-EMPLEADOS
           END-PERFORM.
           DISPLAY "INGRESE COBROS DE CADA VENTA:".
           PERFORM INGRESO-VENTAS WITH TEST AFTER
                            UNTIL WS-CONTADOR EQUALS WS-SUM-VENTAS
               MOVE WS-COBROS TO WS-REGISTRO-COBROS(1)
           CLOSE  REG-VENDEDORES.
           STOP RUN.

       INGRESO-DATOS-EMPLEADOS.
           DISPLAY "EEE$$$$$VVV".
           ACCEPT WS-VENDEDORES.
           ADD WS-CANTIDAD-VENTAS TO WS-SUM-VENTAS.
       INGRESO-VENTAS.
           ADD 1 TO WS-CONTADOR.
           DISPLAY "$$$$$".
           ACCEPT WS-COBROS.
```

### example input data

```
INGRESE DATOS SOLICITADOS
EEE$$$$$VVV
1  400002
```

Comment: Your error message is saying that WS-CANTIDAD-VENTAS contains 2bb, rather than 002.  The `b` represents a blank or space.  Your input doesn't match your WS-VENDEDORES definition.

Comment: yes, and that's what i don't know how to fix or find a workaround, am i forced to enter a value that is of the same lengh as the declared variable otherwise it will fill it with spaces?

Comment: Edit your question to include a few lines of your input.  If you say a field is numeric, like 999, then all three characters must be between 0 and 9.

Comment: I see, so it must have the same lenght, there i edited my question and added an input example, i tought that if i have a pic 99 and entered a value of 5 for example, it would place the number to the far right like 05, but it adds a "5 ". Thank you very much.

Comment: Correct.  You have to enter 05 for a PIC 99.

Answer (score 1):

There is no implicit conversion in `ACCEPT data-item`, so you need to convert - and validate it on your own (or switch to "extended" screenio with `ACCEPT data-item AT` / `SCREEN SECTION`, but then the result would be depending on the actual COBOL environment).

The easiest option to convert (will sip leading/trailing spaces and invalid data) is something like the following:

```
            ACCEPT WS-VENDEDORES.  *> all data may now be invalid
            MOVE FUNCTION NUMVAL (WS-EMPLEADO)        TO WS-EMPLEADO
            MOVE FUNCTION NUMVAL (WS-SUELDO-BASE)     TO WS-SUELDO-BASE
            MOVE FUNCTION NUMVAL (WS-CANTIDAD-VENTAS) TO WS-CANTIDAD-VENTAS
      *>    all data is now valid
```

For validation you may want to use `FUNCITON TEST-NUMVAL (data-to-verify)`.

In any case I'd suggest to check out `SCREEN SECTION`, as this would allow you to input the data in three separate fields and commonly would do validation and conversion "on the fly".